# Dictionary List Type Conversion

Tags: python, arrays, django, dictionary

I have a list the following:

```
{('5740',): [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 ('5686',): [1.017556124, 1.126710081, 1.096176358, 1.002038429, 1.311705968]}
```

I want to get this list like:

```
{('5740',): [array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
     ('5686',): [array([1.017556124, 1.126710081, 1.096176358, 1.002038429, 1.311705968])]}
```

How to do this conversion for all elements of first list.

Comment: It does not seem to make much sense to wrap the `array(..)` in a singleton list?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand but ı want to use this list dtaidistance in dtw algorithm. Maybe I got it wrong, but the list for the dtw algorithm should be given like  second this.

Comment: for key, value in a.items(): 
        a[key] = [np.asarray(value)]

Comment: Thanks @muhammedfairoosnm it is working.